# Not able to connect to MariaDB hosted on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, php, networking, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I'm coding a little project in java, in which I want to compare the inserted password with stored sql input.

Everything is hosted on my Raspberry Pi 3:

- Apache 2.4.37
- Php 7.4.5
- MariaDB 10.0
- phpMyAdmin 5.0.2

The pc i'm conding on and the raspberry are in the same network. 
I can access the database easily with phpMyAdmin, but not in my Java code. (raspberrypi/phpmyadmin), (localhost:3306 returns: localhost refused to connect)

Here are some steps i've did:

- opened the ports
- changed the bind-adress from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in the mariadb settings
- (skip-networking wasn't even in my config) & set the port to 3306
- added the mariadb-java-client-2.6 to my library in the java code

The main exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused: connect
```

everything else:

```
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1346)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:634)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at sample.SQL.<init>(SQL.java:16)
    at sample.Login.initialize(Login.java:55)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused: connect
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:183)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:255)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:512)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1341)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:250)
    ... 27 more
```

The refused connection sounds like a port or permission problem, but I've literally tried everything in the last asked questions here about this topic.

Thanks in advance for reading and any help :)

Comment: Your question suggests that your application on a separate computer to your Pi? If that's true then the error message saying it can't connect to the database on localhost is a clue to the problem! If I've misunderstood and the app and dB server are on the same machine then you can ignore me.

Comment: Sorry for maybe misleading. I'm talking about two different systems. My raspberry pi and my coding computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling so dumb right now.

I once had another RaspberryPi connected, so all the time I opened the port on the wrong devices and even copied the wrong ip.

After changing that I only had to fix the permission problem with:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try from a shell

```
telnet <pi_IP> 3306
```

This would show if the port is open at all. This would show, if your settings of the mariaDB server are at least open the port and the server is running. There could be still a firewall (eg. iptables or firewalld) running and prevent the port from being reached

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I used Test-NetConnection localhost -port 3306 and tried again with the IP of my raspberrypi. The answer: TCP connect failed and PING failed with Status: DestinationHostUnreachable